# Highcharts - Large Tree Map: Show values below points name

Tags: javascript, highcharts, treemap

Is it possible to show values of points below the points name, for example -

```
South -East Asia

1258
```

My fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sachinpsingh/o0t61pzx/

Comment: I try but sorry. don't support multiline. maybe you can find another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing the [format of the dataLabels](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.dataLabels.format) like this:

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  format: '{point.name}<br/>{point.value}'
},
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/o0t61pzx/12/